# SSH and SSH2 compatibility

Tags: security, shell, unix, ssh

I'm trying to set up a passwordless login to the remote host.

First of all, I generated a key pair using this command

```
ssh-keygen -t dsa
```

However on the second step when I have to copy public key to the remote host I see .ssh2 folder instead of .ssh. This folder contains file ".authorization" and no ".authorized_keys2". I'm kind of lost at this point.

```
tom [local-host] /home/tom: ssh -V
OpenSSH_5.2p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8k 25 Mar 2009

tom [remote-host] /home/tom/: ssh -V
ssh: F-Secure SSH 3.2.0 (build 7) on rs6000-ibm-aix
```

Can you please advise on how to set it up properly?

Comment: I think this is off-topic for stackexchange, but I've voted to migrate it somewhere appropriate. If others agree it will get moved automatically.

Comment: @awoodland: suggestion for next time: Mention what target you voted for. In this case SuperUser and ServerFault are equally valid (IMO) and I don't know how it works if everyone votes for a different target ;)

Comment: true - I usually do, mention that, but I was undecided between superuser and serverfault and I didn't want to bias other voters judgement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a deep look at [this site](http://www.ict.griffith.edu.au/anthony/info/apps/ssh.hints), it even tells you how to convert from ssh1 to ssh2.

Answer (score 0):

Problems with password-less logins can be caused by many things (there are a lot of links in the chain, if any are broken the whole thing won't work), so this may not be just an SSH/SSH2 issue.

I notice that you mentioned an `.authorized_keys2` file, but I've always used an `authorized_keys` or `authorized_keys2` file (note there's no leading ".").  I would recommend making a `.ssh` folder and appending your public key (probably the `id_dsa.pub` file) to `.ssh/authorized_keys`.  Ensure the permissions are correct for this entire directory and try logging in again.

You may be able to debug the situation by running `tail -f /var/log/secure` if you've got permission on the remote server.